# How to add boto3 output into a new file and upload it back to an AWS s3 bucket using one script?

Tags: python, pandas

The purpose of the code below is to read a `pdf` file located in `s3 bucket` and list the values of the `pdf` in the terminal. My end goal is to load those values into a `csv/xlsx` and upload it to the same `s3 bucket`. In other words, this is a file conversion from `pdf` to `xlsx`.

Adding item to_excel at the end is not loading the data to excel, any suggestions? the code below is only creating an empty `xlsx` file on the local directory but I need it to do the following:

1. save the data in xlsx listed in the terminal from reading the pdf located in `s3`
2. take that `xlsx` file that has the terminal data and upload it back to `s3`

```
import boto3
import time
import pandas as pd

# Textract APIs used - "start_document_text_detection", "get_document_text_detection"
def InvokeTextDetectJob(s3BucketName, objectName):
    response = None
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
            DocumentLocation={
                      'S3Object': {
                              `enter code here`      'Bucket': s3BucketName,
                                    'Name': objectName
                                }
           })
    return response["JobId"]

def CheckJobComplete(jobId):
    time.sleep(5)
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    status = response["JobStatus"]
    print("Job status: {}".format(status))
    while(status == "IN_PROGRESS"):
        time.sleep(5)
        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
        status = response["JobStatus"]
        print("Job status: {}".format(status))
    return status

def JobResults(jobId):
    pages = []
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
 
    pages.append(response)
    print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
    nextToken = None
    if('NextToken' in response):
        nextToken = response['NextToken']
        while(nextToken):
            response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId, NextToken=nextToken)
            pages.append(response)
            print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
            nextToken = None
            if('NextToken' in response):
                nextToken = response['NextToken']
    return pages

# S3 Document Data
s3BucketName = "pdfbucket"
documentName = "pdf"

# Function invokes
jobId = InvokeTextDetectJob(s3BucketName, documentName)
print("Started job with id: {}".format(jobId))
if(CheckJobComplete(jobId)):
    response = JobResults(jobId)
    for resultPage in response:
        for item in resultPage["Blocks"]:
            if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
                print (item["Text"])

with pd.ExcelWriter('output_cp.xlsx') as writer:
    item.to_excel(writer, sheetName='Sheet1')
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working? Could you add more details on the error you're running into?

Comment: Thank you for taking a shot at this. I'm new here! So I have added this at the end: ```with pd.ExcelWriter('output_cp.xlsx') as writer:
    item.to_excel(writer, sheetName='Sheet1') ```Right now, it is creating an empty xlsx file on my local directory. But I need the file filled with the data from the terminal which is produced by reading a pdf from s3. then take that xlsx file and load it back to the s3 bucket

Comment: Could you remove the aws and boto3 tags and add pandas to this question?
Also, please add what "item" contains.  Looks like item is empty.

Comment: item contains the output of the pdf file.  the statement ``` print (item["Text"]) ``` does print out the values of the pdf in the terminal. so I wanna take those values, put them in xlsx and upload it to s3.

Comment: From your code, item is used only for resultPage, so i doubt it'll have entire data.  If the last iteration had no data, then item would be empty.  Try adding a print(item) before trying the write to excel file.  If that's empty, store what you need into a different dataframe and then write that instead of item.

Comment: Thank you @vivekveeramani I was able to make it work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more research and checking with other people, below is the final product.

The purpose of this code is the following:

1. Read a `pdf` file stored in an `AWS S3 Bucket`
2. After reading the file, save the data as text in a new `xlsx` file

```
import boto3
import time
import pandas as pd
from xlsxwriter import Workbook

# Textract APIs used - "start_document_text_detection", "get_document_text_detection"


def InvokeTextDetectJob(s3BucketName, objectName):
    response = None
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
        DocumentLocation={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': s3BucketName,
                'Name': objectName
            }
        })
    return response["JobId"]


def CheckJobComplete(jobId):
    time.sleep(5)
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    status = response["JobStatus"]
    print("Job status: {}".format(status))
    while(status == "IN_PROGRESS"):
        time.sleep(5)
        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
        status = response["JobStatus"]
        print("Job status: {}".format(status))
    return status


def JobResults(jobId):
    pages = []
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)

    pages.append(response)
    print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
    nextToken = None
    if('NextToken' in response):
        nextToken = response['NextToken']
        while(nextToken):
            response = client.get_document_text_detection(
                JobId=jobId, NextToken=nextToken)
            pages.append(response)
            print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
            nextToken = None
            if('NextToken' in response):
                nextToken = response['NextToken']
    return pages


# S3 Document Data
s3BucketName = "cpaypdf"
documentName = "cp.pdf"

# Function invokes
jobId = InvokeTextDetectJob(s3BucketName, documentName)
print("Started job with id: {}".format(jobId))
if(CheckJobComplete(jobId)):
    response = JobResults(jobId)
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        columns=[
            "Text"
        ]
    )
    for resultPage in response:
        for item in resultPage["Blocks"]:
            if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
                df = df.append({
                    "Text": item['Text']
                },
                    ignore_index=True
                )
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("result.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='sheetname', index=False)
    writer.save()
```